# how go to a path on cinnamon

Tags: bash, cinnamon, extension

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with "Cinnamon" installed, and I wish to install 
this exstension : http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/3

I tried to install it this way:

1) Copied the folder "CoverflowAltTab@dmo60.de" to "~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/".

2) Enabled the extension in the cinnamon settings. (Eventually you have to restart cinnamon: Press Alt+F2, type 'r' and enter)

The problem is that I can`t locate this path : ~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/

Comment: Open your home folder and hit Ctrl+H; `~/.local` should become visible, and you should be able to navigate to `~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/`; alternatively, run `nemo ~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/` in a terminal

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and create the folder

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/
```

and copy the extracted folder into the created folder, e.g.

```
cp ~/Downloads/CoverflowAltTab@dmo60.de ~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/
```

Comment: send this error : mkdir hadi/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘hadi/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/’: No such file or directory1

Comment: with the leading `~`. Copy the command exactly.